# is boiling of water an isobaric process?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is the conversion of water into steam at 100°C an isobaric process? It is an isothermal process, but does pressure rain constant during this process?Please explain as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. Have you ever boiled water in a pot? The steam tries to escape because it creates too much pressure. 
It's just a simple matter of gases being less dense than liquids. As liquid water is converted to gas, it expands which increases the pressure.

Comment: But boiling point is the temp at which vapour pressure becomes equal to external pressure(which is 760torr=constant).. if pressure will change, a change in boiling point will take place and hence, water will not convert into steam at 100°C..doesn't this imply that the process is isobaric as well?

Comment: In a closed system (let's say you boil water in a pot with a screwed down lid) the water will not all boil away unless you increase the temperature. In a more open system, say a boiling pot with no lid, as soon as the water boils it evaporates into steam which is hotter than the air around it and rises, thus making way for cool air to sink down. This maintains the external pressure.
So in a closed system, like a typical pot, the internal pressure increases as the water increases.
Overall though, if you boil water and it is converted to steam, it will exert more pressure.